# Android Development - Login Logic

Tags: android, session

I'm new to Android development and I have a few questions regarding logging in with a database and the logic behind everything from that point forward.  I understand that in order to login, you have to be able to check the username and password with the database you are connected to.  However, I'm confused on what happens from that point forward.

How does an Android application typically keep track of your login status?  Surely the session has to expire at some point.

Does the application check to see if you are logged in just *once* when it logs in, or is it hardcoded that the application has to send the username and password to the database *every single time* a new screen is loaded, as well as check to see if the time has expired?  Somebody has told me before that you can have one main activity constantly keeping track of the login status, and you could have every other activity be inside of that main activity.  I feel that this isn't the way to go.

I've done work in the past with Netbeans, where we had a LoginBean that was SessionScoped and kept track of the session, along with Glassfish.  We were able to set the permissions of the pages that each role was able to view.  It also kept track of when the session expired.  Android seems different because it doesn't seem that you can simply just restrict folders of activities.

If somebody could give me a really dumbed down explanation of the login/authentication logic, that would be wonderful.  We're looking into using OAuth2.  I'm new to Android development, *as well as* login systems in general.  I'm also new to access tokens as well.

Comment: Normally you would acquire an access token and pass it with each request you make. As soon as the token gets outdated, the request would fail, then you need to refresh it and retry.

Comment: Thank you!  Do you have to hard code the access token with each request?  Or is there something managing it behind the scenes?

Comment: Android has the AccountManager API that you can use to store the tokens, check this article: https://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/authenticate.html

Comment: Thank you so much, I saw this resource was out there (but I saw a million other candidates as well).  I'm glad to know that this is the most conventional direction

Comment: Well, I can't say that's the only right way to go, the AccountManager framework is not too straightforward to use, so sometimes it makes more sense to implement token management on your own. Still, I'd recommend to read about it, give it a try and see whether it works for you.

Comment: One more question -with this method, how do i differentiate the activities that are viewable from everybody and the activities that only logged-in users with set permissions can see?  Is there a way to set permissions for the different types of activities with this method?

Comment: Android does not provide (AFAIK) an out-of-the-box solution for this problem.